# Pivots in quicksort : does it have to be an array element?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm a physicist, please excuse my ignorance :(

Does the pivot have to be an array element? If so, why? Does choosing an array element as pivot offer any considerable advantage?

I ask this because choosing the average of the array elements seems like it would be fairly robust (avoid cases where the subarrays are 1 and N-1 long etc). The average might not be an array element (eg: it could be a float for an array of integers)

Thanks!

Comment: (For what it's worth, it's not hard to come up with a case where using the average as the pivot actually gets you the worst-case runtime.)

Comment: Wikipedia's quicksort page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) has some information on pivot selection that might be helpful.

Comment: Yea, mostly curious as to whether it would defeat the purpose of using QS by raising the average runtime. It doesn't seem so to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could very easily implement a version of quicksort that doesn't require the pivot to be an actual element of an array.  The algorithm would work fine with some simple modifications.  But you'd have to code it up yourself: the standard quicksort does require the pivot to be an element of the array.

I'm not sure what the advantage of that would be, though.  First, the average is not guaranteed to be a good pivot.  Also, since this requires iterating through the whole array, and this would happen during recursive calls also, it could slow down the algorithm enough to overcome any advantage from superior pivot selection.

A pretty good strategy for getting a good pivot is to choose a small random sample (say 10 elements) and then choose the median of this sample.

Comment: Yea, that was my original idea. Averaging might be ok for smaller arrays, but I was going use 1000 random elements or so when trying it out on 1 million+ size arrays. Thanks!

Comment: In most cases, the median of 1000 random elements is going to be a better pivot (i.e. closer to the true median) than the average of the whole array.  It depends on your data, but if there is any skewness at all, then the median of such a large random sample will be superior.

Comment: Question is about the cost of getting that median. It may (or may not, ofcourse) turn out to generate a big constant time multiplier, in which case it would be reasonable to choose some guaranteed nlogn algorithm (like heapsort or mergesort).

Comment: @Byakuya Yes, that is why taking 1000 random elements to find a pivot is probably overkill.  Median can be found in constant time, so asymptotically choosing o(n) elements for median finding wouldn't affect the performance, even by a constant factor.  In practice, though, choosing 10 or maybe 50 elements should work fine.

Comment: How to find a median of unsorted table in constant time?

Comment: Randomized is easy: basically you do quicksort but only recurse down one side.  It's also possible to do it deterministically, but that's more complicated.  Google "deterministic median algorithm", e.g. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s07/www/lecture_notes/lect0125.pdf

Comment: It is about finding a median in linear time, which I know, I think you must have misspelled it. But finding in linear time does increase the constant factor (even though asymptototical time remains Theta(nlogn)).

Comment: Sorry, yeah, linear time.  No, it does not increase the running time by a constant factor provided you only choose o(n) -- for example sqrt(n) or log(n) -- sample elements and take the median of those to find the pivot.

Comment: I can't see it. If you'll go one of the best ways and choose a median of medians, you'll still need to go through n (or nearly n) elements, and that increases your constant - it takes some time to find the median among those elements, so the time grows bigger.

Comment: Suppose I choose log(n) elements from the original array, and use the median of those log(n) elements as my pivot.  That means finding the pivot only takes O(log(n)) time, which is o(n) (little-o).  The resulting increase in the running time of the algorithm will be o(n log n), less than a constant factor.